# No Audio in Android-x86

Tags: android, alsa, android-x86

I've setup an [Android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) image (4.0-RC1-eeepc) in VirtualBox on a Dell Latitude D820.  This particular ISO is not for the laptop, but of all available ISOs it works the best.

I have worked through some of the troubles I have come across (by not having an ISO for my device), but I haven't been able to get the sound working.  The Android-x86 VirtualBox tutorial and other online resources directed me to use the ALSA driver with SoundBlaster 16, but this has not worked.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894582/alsa-aplay-not-recording-on-android) question got me to look at some of the ALSA commands to see what I could find, but I'm not getting anywhere with it.

With the ALSA driver and SoundBlaster controller I get the following from `alsa_ctl init`

```
Unknown hardware: "Dummy" "Dummy Mixer"
Hardware is initialized using a guess method
```

This looked very wrong to me so switched to the Intel HD Audio as the other question did.

With the ALSA driver and Intel HD Audio controller I get the following from `alsa_ctl init`

```
Unknown hardware: "HDA-Intel" "SigmaTel ID 7680" ...
Hardware is initialized using a guess method
```

While this looks a little more promising, I still have no audio.

Since Android is *basically* Linux, I thought I would be able to translate a Linux solution.  Several webpages have content similar to [this one](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1475185&page=2) saying to modify `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and add `options snd-hda-intel model=CORRECT_MODEL` and this appears to help a lot of Linux users.  However, this doesn't seem applicable to Android.  At least not to me, since I don't have `alsa-base.conf`

I know so very little about audio and ALSA.  Is there anyting jumping out from what I have above?  Even a nudge in a general direction would be great.

Some questions that I have:
What does it mean when I get the `Unknown hardware: "Dummy"` info?  No audio device?

Lastly, I have verified that my sound works outside of virtual box.  My first throught is that since my laptop can run Linux with sound, I should be able to include the Linux drivers in Android.  Does that make any sense?  Unfortunately, I also don't really know how to go about doing that either.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a similar no audio problem in vbox. In your init.sh add this line to the end of the alsa_amixer stuff:

`alsa_amixer set PCM 100 unmute`

After I aded that my audio worked fine.

Comment: where is the location of init.sh ?

Comment: I get "mixer attatch default error: no such fine or directory"

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issues.

I was using VMWare for WhatsApp. And had various Android versions without audio...
Setup VMWare with HDAudio config file mod.

```
alsa_ctl init
```

Always showed no devices.

I installed this App from Google Play "[AlsaMixer (ROOT)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skvalex.alsamixer)"
And this versions got audio instantly:

- android-x86-4.3-20130725.iso
- android-x86-4.4-RC1.iso

Comment: what is HDAudio config file mod?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I kept looking for `init.sh` and then realized I had to install the darn thing to disk before that was worth fiddling with (it's re-parsed on reboot and the live disc doesn't save).

So I snagged the latest x86 ports and flipped through them till I found a 4.2x without issues. Sadly I lost track of which is which, and the good one is simply `vm.iso`?!

Long story short, audio is working fine with this build, I didn't even need to tweak anything.

System:

- Motherboard Tab:

  - 4GB RAM (Half the Host RAM)
  - [x] Hard Disk (Only boot device)
  - everything else is default
- Processor Tab:

  - 2 cores
  - everything else is default
- Audio:

  - Windows DirectSound
  - ICH AC97
  - everything else is default

Answer (score 0):

Working on phoenix os and androidx86 for sound fix 
1) Install AlsaMixer apk 
2) Open AlsaMixer 
3) Search Master Playback Volume and edit value to 90