# Audio not working on Android running on Virtualbox?

Tags: android, windows, virtualbox, alsa, android-x86

I installed Android on Virtualbox, I'm using Android x86 downloaded from http://www.android-x86.org/download I chose version 2.3 the eeepc version (android-x86-2.3-RC1-eeepc.iso).

The problem is the sound is not working, I tried all 3 choices in Virtualbox settings.
My current settings:

```
Host driver: Windows DirectSound
Controller: ICH AC97
```

The choices I tried for the audio controller setting:

```
Intel HD Audio
ICH AC97
SoundBlaster 16
```

I'm currently running Windows 7 and my audio driver is the default windows driver.

I searched and found people with the same issue, but I couldn't understand anything as I'm not an advanced Linux user some solutions talk about the ALSA driver but I couldn't find how to install it and use it.

Also could it be from the installation .iso file I chose ? my computer is `Acer Travelmate 2480`.

**Update**
While checking the Android x86 website I found that we should [use SoundBlaster 16 instead of ICH AC97](http://www.android-x86.org/documents/virtualboxhowto).

I also tried the `alsa_ctl init` command inside the terminal (ALT + F1), and I got this:

```
Unkown hardware: "Dummy" ""Dummy Mixer" "" "" ""
Hardware is initialized using a guess method
```

I checked the version it's 1.0.23

Answer (score 3):

Check for your sound cards detected using

```
alsa_aplay -l
```

and select the first card

```
alsa_ctl init 1
```

Have you checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037254/no-audio-in-android-x86)  of using this

```
alsa_amixer set PCM 100 unmute
```

or do as described [here](http://www.android-x86.org/documents/how-to-make-virtualbox-ich-ac97-audio-work-with-android-eclair-x86)

Read some [crap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture) to understand about Sound Architecture or Try using [VMware Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) or [VMware Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/) its a better alternative, [here](http://quinxy.com/technology/running-android-2-2-in-vmware-in-less-than-5-minutes/) you can find some good tutorials

Comment: vmplayer is never better than virtualbox :) as i believe

Comment: Please read these http://marsbox.com/blog/reviews/vmware-vs-virtualbox/
http://forums.anandtech.com/archive/index.php/t-2137402.html
http://osworker.blogspot.in/2012/01/different-between-vmware-and-virtual.html
http://www.infoworld.com/d/virtualization/review-vmware-workstation-9-vs-virtualbox-42-203277. Apart from these what you believe is the best for you ;)

Comment: http://xmodulo.com/2013/07/vmware-player-vs-virtualbox-performance-comparison.html and this http://www.infoworld.com/d/virtualization/review-vmware-workstation-9-vs-virtualbox-42-203277,  then you have FREE ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried a lot fixes/solutions but it didn't work, I'm gonna switch to VMware.

Answer (score 3):

Go to setting of the android virtual machine and select “Audio” and in audio setting select “SoundBlaster 16” as audio controller. The Android-x86 website says that only SoundBlaster 16 works as a VirtualBox soundcard for Android.